# Google Drive Api implementation from SherlockFragmentActivity action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity, google-drive-android-api

I have the following scenario in my app -

SherlockFragmentActivity hosting a ViewPager containing 3 individual fragments. There is a sherlockactionbar on top, with backup and restore options, which should basically backup the app data to google drive account (connected to the user).

Now, everything works fine, wrt the backup-restore as well, by opening up the Google Api Client connection and uploading / downloading file, but as soon as the device rotates, the Activity is restarted from scratch and the google api client instance created and instantiated ealier (may be upload / download is also still in progress) becomes orphan.
I get a **IllegalStateException** (due to the activity restart, while the instance still needs an original activity to tie back to).

Knowing, that the Fragments themselves can be retained across activity restarts, I can put the drive api implementation in fragment, **but having a common action bar icon on top, wouldn't it be a repetition to just put drive implementation on all 3 fragments??**
Also, **when the ViewPager swipe occurs, the fragment will be changed, so wouldn't I face the same issue again, wherein the original drive api client instance creator fragment is no longer in scope.?**

What is a good way to implement such a thing? Any ideas would help me to research in given direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have a viewpager and several fragments, just as your case. I let the my activity class extend the BaseDriveActivity from the Google-drive-exapmle, but letting it extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity.

The rotation was not any problem, even if onResume is called during rotation, sinde it is checking if mGoogleApiClient is null:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    }
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

There is some logic for errorhandling as well. You can use it as is.

The operations for creating a folder, creating a folder inside a foldet etc I added to my main class like this:

```
protected void createFolder(String folderName){
       MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
        .setTitle(folderName).build();
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).createFolder(
        getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet).setResultCallback(createFolderCallback);
}

final ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> createFolderCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());

    }
};


private String folderName;

protected void createFolderInFolder(String exsistingDriveId, String folderName){
    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), exsistingDriveId).setResultCallback(idCallback);
    this.folderName=folderName;
}

final ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }
        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi
                .getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle(folderName).build();
        folder.createFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet)
                .setResultCallback(createFolderCallback);
    }
};

private DriveId mFolderDriveId;


protected void createFileInFolder(String exsistingDriveId, String folderName){
    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(),       exsistingDriveId).setResultCallback(fileIdCallback);
    this.folderName=folderName;
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> fileIdCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>()        {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }
        mFolderDriveId = result.getDriveId();
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient())
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }
        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), mFolderDriveId);
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle(folderName)
                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                .setStarred(true).build();
        folder.createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Created a file: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
    }
};
```

EDIT:
I have found the following: 
if  createFolderInFolder (or any other of the api-funcions) is called, just before an intent is used to call an activity, the result-callback will not be called while the called activity is running. When the main activity is receiving control, the onResume is called, and giving an exception, since connect is called again. Then the result-callback is never called.

This means that the api-call and the result-callback must be able to run without any other calls being run.

New Edit:
Step1: You need a callback function in your Fragment

```
private Callbacks mCallbacks;

interface Callbacks {
    public void onSaveToDrive(byte[] filecontent);
}
```

Step2: The main activity must implement the fragment callback-methods

Step3: Call the api-function, and add the fragment-update call in the result-callback

If you would like to store the driveid, you should use DriveId.encodeFromString(exsistingDriveId) and DriveId.decodeFromString(exsistingDriveId) in this way you can store the existingDriveId, and safely refer to it again at a later stage, even if the drive has been disconnected and reconnected.

Remember one api-call must be done without calling other classes, since that may cause the onResume() to be called.

Comment: So what essentially happens when a drive connection is already initiated in onResume and the activity restarts due to rotation. Wouldn't the existing drive task continue in background and there would again be a new connection created in onResume (2nd time), causing the earlier object call to fail when it completes and tries to tie back to original object?

Comment: Yes, I belive you are right. However onConnectionFailed be called during the attempt to do the second connection. That should handle the error and keep the first connection, if it is still alive. Is that not true in your case?

Comment: Let me check this scenario out, but I believe, it doesn't, as you technically try and call another driveobject.connect() method, without ever having to go into the onConnectionFailed. The onConnectionFailed is a callback interface automatically invoked by the drive api, when there is some connection issue. but in case, when the connection has already been established previous (before rotation), there is no reason why onConnectionfailed should be called

Comment: I finally found the solution to the problem. I have edited my answer

Comment: So you mean, this solution, works from an activity allowing to control the google drive api function calls for viewpager fragments even when the activity goes thru rotation cycle? In that case, can you please post a more detailed code for both the activity, baseactivity and the fragment?

Comment: No. My findings was that it works if the call to the api and the result-call is made in the activity without any calls to fragments nor activity in between. Then the destroy will not be called.

Comment: Added some code in onStart and onResume:  replaced connect()-call with: if (!mGoogleApiClient.conected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())     mGoogleApiClient.connect();